# "Carry" value to next .map

Tags: rx-java

Maybe the title is misleading. Please change at will.

I have an Observable (Subject) which emits a value. I want to pass this value to generate a new observable (via flatMap) but also pass it down to the flatMap's operation:

```
getAddressSubject
     .flatMap(latLng -> getApiManagerInstance().getAddress(latLng))
     .map(addressResponse ->{
          // here I want to use both latLng and addressResponse
          // e.g:
         createObject(latLng, addressResponse);
     })
```

Comment: I asked a very similar question on Monday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002252/any-rx-operator-that-returns-both-the-input-variable-and-the-result/28034900#28034900

Comment: @ExactaBox Not really. Your `getTweetText()` returns a HashMap while on my case the method returns an observable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `map` operator into the `flatMap` operator like:

```
getAddressSubject
    .flatMap(latLng ->
        getApiManagerInstance().getAddress(latLng).map(
           addressResponse -> createObject(latLng, addressResponse))
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my best solution so far.

Since subjects can be used many times you "duplicate" the context and you use one of them as pure and the other to trigger the second observable.
Then you zip them together:

```
zip(    getAddressSubject,
        getAddressSubject
                .throttleLast(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(latLng -> getApiManagerInstance().getAddress(latLng)),
        (latLng, response) -> createObject(latLng, response)
))
```